# Local properties of harmonic forms on riemannian manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Consider a riemannian manifold together with a orthogonal basis $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\}$ of the space of harmonic $k$-form. I suspect that the inner product $\langle \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rangle$ for $i \neq j$ is "small" when restricted to any codimension 0 submanifold. By "small" I mean an expression that depends only on the volume of the submanifold, the norms of the forms and potentially a curvature term? Is some local property like this true?